# "mising software and update tools"

Tags: tools

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, I can't find "software and update tools" from dash or system settings. How to install it? I need it to check my wireless network adapter because it is not recognised by Ubuntu.

Comment: Open a terminal  (ctl alt t) type update-manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix missing items in your setting or control panel by uninstalling and reinstalling the control center.

unity-control-center

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center && sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Or

```
sud apt-get install --reinstall unity-control-center
```

You can reinstall the update manager by doing the following in a terminal please check if you have it first with

```
update-manager
```

If not run updates and upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then install.

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall update-manager
```

Answer (score 1):

You must execute in terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk
```